# Is this possible to use an Android SDK into a standalone desktop JAVA application?

Tags: java, android, sdk, desktop

I'm trying to do an application, that can pilot a parrot jumping sumo drone but there is no existing JAVA library, so I tought : "Is this possible to use an Android SDK into a standalone desktop JAVA application ?"

Hope you can answer me !

Joseph

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible to use an Android SDK into a standalone desktop JAVA application?

No. There may be a couple of utility classes that you could get from the Android source code that would work on ordinary Java. Most of what is in the Android SDK is tied to the Android OS.